# Issue restoring Sql Server DB -

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, sql

Im trying to restore one our DB on Sql2008r2 but i keep getting this error:
" netStagingDB_log.ldf' is claimed by 'ftrow_FTCat_Sheds' and 'ftrow_FTCat_Codes'. The WITH MOVE clause can be used to relocate one or more files."

But i only have the "ftrow_FTCat_Sheds" as the logical names of the DB.
Should "ftrow_FTCat_Codes" be a 2nd data files , how could i through the WebsitePanel restore this DB under a different name.

### Platform

Win 2008 Server R2 64bit
Sql 2008 r2

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [**WebSitePanel user guide**](http://www.websitepanel.net/user-guide/backing-up-and-restoring-sql-server-database) for backing up and restoring a database, it doesn't look like you can without some backend trickery.  There aren't any options for the Restore feature.  That means that if you already have a copy of this database on your server with the same physical file name you're out of luck.

You could try this as a workaround, if you have a local SQL Server 2008 R2 instance available to you:

1. Restore your database from your bakup file
2. Detach the database
3. Rename the log file (the physical .ldf file)
4. Reattach the database using the new log file name
5. Perform a new backup of the database
6. Restore the backup through WebsitePanel using the new backup file

That should work for you.  Other than that you'd need to have some kind of application on the server that connects to to the SQL instance and allows you to execute SQL statements.

Comment: I did try these but unfortunately it didnt worked out. I guess i ll have to use the SSMS and try to do the restore.